# asp.net Logic to check if user already exist

Tags: sql, asp.net, if-statement

I have this code to check if a user already exists, but it is not working.

For some reason system is skipping this function:

```
if Cadastrar_CodEmpresa = verificar("Usuario") Then
    Response.Redirect("index.asp?pagina=login")
```

Here is the code:

```
if request.Form("commentForm") = "sim"   Then
    set verificar = conexao.execute ("select * from empresas")

    Cadastrar_CodEmpresa = request.Form("CodEmpresa")
    Cadastrar_Segmento = request.Form("Segmento")
    Cadastrar_Endereco = request.Form("Endereco")
    Cadastrar_Bairro = request.Form("Bairro")
    Cadastrar_Cidade = request.Form("Cidade")
    Cadastrar_CEP = request.Form("CEP")
    Cadastrar_Pais = request.Form("Pais")
    Cadastrar_Contato = request.Form("Contato")
    Cadastrar_Telefone = request.Form("Telefone")
    Cadastrar_Email = request.Form("email")

    if Cadastrar_CodEmpresa = verificar("Usuario")  Then
        response.Redirect("index.asp?pagina=login")
    Else
        set cadastrar_cadastro = conexao.execute("insert into Empresas (Usuario) Values ('" & Cadastrar_CodEmpresa & "')")
    End if

    ... some more stuff ...

End if
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking here. Is the second if statement being skipped all together? Or is it taking the else branch when you expect it to take the then branch? Is that bit of code above your code block actually part of the code or are you just trying to direct us to the problem area in the code block?

Comment: yes it is just a block of the code that i'm direct to the problem area in the code block,  This is all the code: http://pastebin.com/CCjub4NS

Comment: So, 
It is not very clear what you are asking here. Is the second if statement being skipped all together? Or is it taking the else branch when you expect it to take the then branch?

Comment: i just wan't to know why why this statment is not working if Cadastrar_CodEmpresa = verificar("Usuario")  Then
              response.Redirect("index.asp?pagina=login")

Comment: What do you expect, and what is it doing?

Comment: suposte to work, i'm chekcing if yes create all variables then if Variable Cadsatrar_CodeEmpresa = Usuario ( At my SQL) then redidrect to another page ( Login)

Comment: Supposed to work, and doesn't work are both very vague. There are millions of possibilities based on what you expect, and what is happening. Are you getting errors? Is `verificar()` a stock ASP.NET function. I suspect not because it isn't English as `response.Redirect` is. What is it supposed to do? You need to give us specifics.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy verificar is the result of `conexao.execute ("select * from empresas")`. So presumably some sort of SQL result, but we don't know for sure what it is because we don't know the type of `conexao`.

Comment: @RaphaelGuarita have you set debug points to check that `Cadastrar_CodEmpresa` contains the value you exepct, and that `verificar("Usuario")` contains the value you expect? Your SQL could return multiple rows, but you only seem to be checking against 1 row (and I'm not even 100% sure that will work because we don't know what sort of object `verificar` is. I suspect you need to loop through all the rows. Either that or put a WHERE clause into your SQL to find the row with the matching username - that would be much more efficient.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you need more information on how to execute an SQL Query in ASP.NET. Here is an answer that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9005575/2296441

Comment: @ADyson,  thank you so much for response, i will try debug this variables